# Funcão recursiva em python para inverter um número

Tags: python

Preciso fazer uma função recursiva em python para retornar o número da forma invertida, porém ser converter em string.

Eu só consegui fazer dessa forma:

```
import math

def inverte(num):
 if(num < 10):
   return num

  q=num//10
  q=inverte(q)

  r=num%10
  inv=r*10**((math.floor(math.log10(q)+1)))+q

  return inv

 print(inverte(1234))
```

Porém, meu professor disse que eu poderia fazer apenas usando divisão inteira e resto. Alguém ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução até simples, porém uma lógica um pouco chata de solucionar. Aqui esta uma maneira de resolver isso utilizando divisão inteira e recursividade, sem a conversão para outros tipos:

```
def inverte(num, aux=0):
    if num < 10:
        return aux + num
    aux = aux * 10 + num % 10 * 10
    return inverte(num // 10, aux)
```

No Python, o operador `//` funciona como um *floor division* (ou divisão inteira, como foi mencionada pelo seu professor).

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer outra dúvida sinta-se a vontade para entrar em contato.

Comment: Na verdade só pode ter um parâmetro essa função. Que seria apenas o número. Dessa forma que você fez eu já tinha pensando, mas só pode ter um parâmetro na função.